Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) while i install pip3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential bzip2 cpp cpp-13
  cpp-13-x86-64-linux-gnu cpp-x86-64-linux-gnu dirmngr dpkg-dev fakeroot fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core
  fonts-dejavu-mono g++ g++-13 g++-13-x86-64-linux-gnu g++-x86-64-linux-gnu gcc gcc-13 gcc-13-base
  gcc-13-x86-64-linux-gnu gcc-x86-64-linux-gnu gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client
  gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm javascript-common libabsl20230802 libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libaom3 libasan8 libassuan0 libatomic1 libavif16
  libbinutils libbz2-1.0 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc-l10n libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcrypt-dev
  libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libdav1d7 libde265-0 libdeflate0 libdpkg-perl libexpat1 libexpat1-dev libfakeroot
  libfile-fcntllock-perl libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgav1-1 libgcc-13-dev libgd3 libgomp1 libgprofng0
  libheif-plugin-aomenc libheif-plugin-dav1d libheif-plugin-libde265 libheif-plugin-x265 libheif1 libhwasan0
  libisl23 libitm1 libjbig0 libjpeg62-turbo libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libksba8 liblerc4
  liblsan0 liblzma5 libmpc3 libmpfr6 libnpth0t64 libnsl-dev libnuma1 libpng16-16 libpython3-dev
  libpython3.11 libpython3.11-dev libquadmath0 librav1e0 libsframe1 libsharpyuv0 libstdc++-13-dev
  libsvtav1enc1d1 libtiff6 libtirpc-dev libtsan2 libubsan1 libwebp7 libx265-199 libxpm4 libyuv0
  linux-libc-dev locales-all make manpages manpages-dev pinentry-curses python3-dev python3-distutils
  python3-lib2to3 python3-wheel python3.11-dev rpcsvc-proto xz-utils zlib1g-dev
Suggested packages:
  binutils-doc gprofng-gui bzip2-doc cpp-doc gcc-13-locales cpp-13-doc pinentry-gnome3 tor debian-keyring
  g++-multilib g++-13-multilib gcc-13-doc gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc
  gcc-13-multilib gdb-x86-64-linux-gnu parcimonie xloadimage scdaemon apache2 | lighttpd | httpd glibc-doc
  bzr libgd-tools libheif-plugin-ffmpegdec libheif-plugin-jpegdec libheif-plugin-jpegenc
  libheif-plugin-j2kdec libheif-plugin-j2kenc libheif-plugin-rav1e libheif-plugin-svtenc libstdc++-13-doc
  make-doc pinentry-doc python3-setuptools
Recommended packages:
  gnupg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential bzip2 cpp cpp-13
  cpp-13-x86-64-linux-gnu cpp-x86-64-linux-gnu dirmngr dpkg-dev fakeroot fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core
  fonts-dejavu-mono g++ g++-13 g++-13-x86-64-linux-gnu g++-x86-64-linux-gnu gcc gcc-13 gcc-13-base
  gcc-13-x86-64-linux-gnu gcc-x86-64-linux-gnu gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client
  gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm javascript-common libabsl20230802 libalgorithm-diff-perl
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libaom3 libasan8 libassuan0 libatomic1 libavif16
  libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcrypt-dev libctf-nobfd0 libctf0 libdav1d7
  libde265-0 libdeflate0 libdpkg-perl libexpat1-dev libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libfontconfig1
  libfreetype6 libgav1-1 libgcc-13-dev libgd3 libgomp1 libgprofng0 libheif-plugin-aomenc
  libheif-plugin-dav1d libheif-plugin-libde265 libheif-plugin-x265 libheif1 libhwasan0 libisl23 libitm1
  libjbig0 libjpeg62-turbo libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libksba8 liblerc4 liblsan0 libmpc3
  libmpfr6 libnpth0t64 libnsl-dev libnuma1 libpng16-16 libpython3-dev libpython3.11 libpython3.11-dev
  libquadmath0 librav1e0 libsframe1 libsharpyuv0 libstdc++-13-dev libsvtav1enc1d1 libtiff6 libtirpc-dev
  libtsan2 libubsan1 libwebp7 libx265-199 libxpm4 libyuv0 linux-libc-dev make manpages manpages-dev
  pinentry-curses python3-dev python3-distutils python3-lib2to3 python3-pip python3-wheel python3.11-dev
  rpcsvc-proto xz-utils zlib1g-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libbz2-1.0 libc-bin libc-l10n libexpat1 liblzma5 locales-all
6 upgraded, 118 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/118 MB of archives.
After this operation, 409 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.37-15) ...
debconf: DbDriver "config": /var/cache/debconf/config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 installed libc6:amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```


I was installing python3-pip when this error code appeared and I don't know how to fix it

It looks like another process is accessing the file - you can use fuser to find out what, and either let it finish or kill it if it does not appear to be completing. See for example "debconf: DbDriver "config": config.dat is locked by another process: Resource temporarily unavailable" while installing packages
